# Is there any way to enhance the performance of csat?

Tags: sql, sas

I am using create table transformation in SAS DI to create a table.

My base table had more than a million records. It is taking more than 24 hours. How can I improve the performance of the operation? Is there an alternative option?

Comment: You need to show the code if you want help with your problem.

Comment: In an ETL tool as DI studio, you do not code, you specify, Gordon. @upadhi, could you supply the log? Also, what is **csat**?